# How to group range of conditional formatting with color scales by category?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I wonder is it possible to use condition formatting with color scales, but to group range of this formating by values from another column.

For example, if I have some category in one column (like **A**, **B** and **C**) and values in another, the cells with values would be formatted, but `maximum` and `minimum` of color scale would be dependent on the category, so cells with values of category **A** would have another `min` and `max` than cells with values of category **B**.

How it looks like with normal conditional formating:

[image]

How I want it to be:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzRtk.jpg]

The categories and values changes every day, and there are several dozen of categories, so I can't just manually create another range for each of them. Is it possible to format values cells in the way I have described?

Comment: Not without  VBA, I don't think. Unless the categories are all contiguous - there's sure to be a complex formula that will group those, but I don't know how it would play with conditional formatting

Comment: I tried it with formulas, and Conditional Formatting is obnoxiously restrictive about what sort of formulas/specifications it will accept. TL;DR: I couldn't get it to work with formulas.

Comment: Ok, so I have to use VBA. Anyways, thank you guys for your attend.